# Notepad++ autocomplete HTML comment tag

Tags: notepad++, html, autocomplete, xml

I've recently enabled N++ autocomplete feature to close `HTML/XML` tags for me.

My problem is with the HTML comment tags: it tries to auto-close them!

I type:
`<!-- comment -->`
And it autocompletes to:
`<!-- comment --></!-->`

Any way to have it behave smarter, so that it doesn't wrongly autocomplete the comment tag, yet autocompletes others as usual?

Comment: Do you need to use notepad++, or are you OK with using other software, I know of a really good html editing program that is very smart.

Comment: This was specific to npp, as I use that for tons of other work.